# Unable to send the TAB key during a Selenium integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, sendkeys

As part of a Selenium integration test, I wrote the two following lines in Ruby to simulate entering an e-mail address into a text field and "moving the focus away":

```
  @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "user@example.com"
  @driver.find_element(:id, "some_other_element").click
```

The second line is not generic enough, because some_other_element might be unknown or non-existent. Thus, I wanted to replace the action of clicking another element with a TAB keystroke:

```
  @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys :tab
```

However, this does not seem to work, the element user_email does not lose its focus as expected. Also replacing :tab with "\xEE\x80\x84" does not help. Does anyone know what could be wrong here? How can I move the focus away of an element without simulating a click somewhere else?

Thanks for any help,
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it without simulating a click, but clicking on `<body>` worked for me. This solution may be generic enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works well. Give it a try.

```
find('.myselector_name').native.send_keys(:tab)
```

Reference to answer is [How do I simulate hitting enter in an input field with Capybara and ChromeDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866946/how-do-i-simulate-hitting-enter-in-an-input-field-with-capybara-and-chromedriver)