# How do I simulate hitting enter in an input field with Capybara and ChromeDriver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following helper method to input a string into an input field and press the enter key, but it seems the enter key is never pressed.  I see the string entered into the input field, but the events that take place upon hitting enter never happened.

I've tested in an actual browser that the enter key correctly fires the expected events.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
def fill_and_trigger_enter_keypress(selector, value)
  page.execute_script %Q(
                          var input = $('#{selector}');
                          input.val('#{value}');
                          input.trigger("keypress", [13]);
                         )
end
```

EDIT:

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
find('#q_name').native.send_keys(:return)
find('#q_name').native.send_keys(:enter)
```

They don't cause any error, but still no enter key pressed.

Answer (score 90):

```
find('#q_name').native.send_keys(:return)
```

works for me. I dont have a name or id for my field but the type is input so i used something like

```
find('.myselector_name>input').native.send_keys(:return)
```

works perfectly fine!

Comment: As an additional info, Selinium doesn't simulate key events on hidden elements, whereas this solution works fine even with hidden elements.

Comment: @Mysterio Man This solution isn't working with Capybara 2.5. It throws `NoMethodError: undefined method `send_keys' for "5":String` error.

Answer (score 37):

These days (Capybara version 2.5+) you can simulate the `<enter>` key in the following way:

```
find('.selector').set("text\n")
```

The `\n` (new line) is the very important bit here.

Answer (score 6):

Usually when you run page.execute_script, you get the same results as if you were running that in the page console. Try running that manually in the console and see if you get the expected results. That is usually what I do.. craft the needed js code in the browser console window and paste it into the capybara code when it is working, using execute_script.

Comment: Working on that.  I don't get any errors when I do $('#input_selector').trigger('keyPress', [13]), but still nothing seems triggered as if I were to hit enter in the browser.

Comment: yeah so you probably have to tweak the event you are triggering. try triggering a focus event first, to simulate that you clicked the input to enter it, and then the keyPress.. what I found is that you usually have to play with the right events

Comment: this is what I do to fill an autocomplete, for example:

    page.execute_script %Q{$('#{selector}').val('#{value}').focus().keydown()}

Comment: Sounds like code driven tests... instead of test driven code :)

Answer (score 5):

Capybara doesn't have native support for a send_keys type event. You might be able to go down to selenium to do it, or you can try this gem https://github.com/markgandolfo/send-keys

Comment: Great, I'll check out that gem.  But Capybara shouldn't be the issue since I'm sending the jQuery directly to selenium, right?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
page.execute_script("$('form.css-class/#form_id').submit()")
```

Comment: `$('form.css-class/#form_id')` isn't valid jQuery - running it throws an error.

Comment: I think it needs to be formatted without the slash, so
`$('form.css-class#form_id')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill_in` as usual, but append a newline character `"\n"` to the `with:` value. The `with:` value must be in double quotes, not single quotes. This will trigger a form submission:

```
fill_in "q_name", with: "hello world\n"
```

Comment: This is a correct way to do it. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

`@Page.selector.send_keys :return`

This works for me, where `selector` is the element in your page object
element `:selector, '<css selector>'`