# using rspec capybara, how to enter "enter" to a inputbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For a input box

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-2" id="s2id_autogen2_search" placeholder="">
```

I would like to set its value as "name" and followed by enter (as press the keyboard)

I tried to write it as

`find('input#s2id_autogen2_search',visible:false).set(@user.email+'\n')`

but it does not work, anyone can help me with that?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866946/how-do-i-simulate-hitting-enter-in-an-input-field-with-capybara-and-chromedriver

Comment: @gotva I tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (notice the double quotation):

```
find('input#s2id_autogen2_search',visible:false).set(@user.email + "\n")
```